# AngularJS nav stateProvider plus angular ui router with left & right sliding page transitions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've spent dozens of hours trying to find ( and build ) an AngularJS nav example that uses stateProvider plus angular ui router with left & right sliding page transitions, to no avail.  It sounds simple enough, but every example I have looked at only slides in one direction ( all views come in from the left or the right hand side only ) . The only  exception to this I've seen uses history.back() plus a right sliding transition, so it only suits blind alley navigation ( e.g. back button ). The approach I am using is to set a class in the main view to "slide-left" or "slide-right", and then let  the animation classes ( .ng-enter, .ng-leave, etc. ) handle the transitions. Unfortunately, I have found it to be flakey... either that or I am really not getting what's actually happening. The transitions also look clunky, because of the way only the exiting page slides. You can see a "typical" left right slide example, that I have based my later work on, here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview

I have a working jQuery / HTML5 version here: http://embed.plnkr.co/LpsDJM0ZDMm8QouQXuBB/preview. This is pretty much the operation I want in AngularJS (1.2+ ). Does anyone know how to make the views in Angular play nicely like this? Thanks in  advance!

Comment: did you check ui-router sample app - http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/ ? it does quite simmilar things - several nested states, with animated transitions, here is its source - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/gh-pages/sample

Comment: thanks, I looked over that one earlier in my research, and decided there was a huge amount of stuff ( and files ) I'd have to strip from it to evaluate it. The main angular files are the same as I'm using ( 1.2.x angular, angular-ui-router and angular-animate ) and the transitions in css seem based on the same examples mine. I'll post a failed example later. :)